# The difference between exclude_hv and exclude_host in perf

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, hardware, perf

In kernel 3.11.0, in the `struct perf_event_attr`, there are three members named `exclude_hv`/`exclude_host`/`exclude_guest`.

I know the `exclude_host` field is to exclude events generated by the host when running kvm. But what is the meaning of `exclude_hv`? Is it used in the Xen?
What is the mechanism in hardware that supports the function of `exclude_host`? As far as I know, in the performance monitoring select registers, there are no such bits that control the event counter to exclude events generated by the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit old but for those looking at the answer, as me:

exclude_hv: do not count events that occur in the hypervisor.

The distinction between events occurred in user space, kernel, hypervisor, host, etc is done in software. The kernel and/or hypervisor will retire and replace the event count and configuration on each change of context.

Here is an excellent [description of perf_events](http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/perf_events/perf_event_open.html), which is the kernel module that handles the performance counters.